# What files should be writable after Magento installation for security?

Tags: linux, apache, security, magento

After an install / setup of Magento on a LAMP Server, what files should be left writable, readable, and/or executable (by owner, group, public)?

What is optimal for a secure magento server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All folders should be 775
All files should be 664.

Now the exceptions:
/var should be writable for everyone (777)
/media folder should allow web to write in it.

You can run those if you have SSH access:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Atleast that is what [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions) suggest.

Comment: if a folder is 777, can a user view/edit my information? eveninformation I do not want them to see?

Comment: yes, 777 means r(ead)w(rite)x(execute) for owner(7)/group(7)/everyone(7).

Comment: I have one more question; for security purposes, wouldnt one want to only leave it read only? Or am i getting this mixed up?

Comment: var folder should be writable. The set is 777 because you can't be sure exacly under what group your webserver is working. /var and /media are the only folders where magento writes/create files in normal usage. If you know for sure that your webserver runs as 'httpd' for example and you have entire magento folder owned by httpd then you can run with 755. Or have magento folders and files owned by httpd then use 775.